# I used "from" and "to" as column titles in my database table, how do I SELECT them?

Tags: mysql

So I made a table with columns "from" and "to".

While writing to the table is fine because I am inserting one value into each column (and not referencing the columns by name), but whenever I want to retrieve data (SELECT), I want to retrieve... say, only the "from" column.

Except as you guessed, it interprets "from" as an SQL command instead of a column name. Surrounding it in quotes just makes "from" populate the result set. Weird.

Can I do anything short of renaming the column? (Which isn't too bad, since the table really has no real data right now).

Thanks!

What I have now:
SELECT from,id FROM permissions

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Backticks should work in this situation.

e.g.

```
SELECT `from` FROM myTable;
```

But ideally you'd rename it. Perhaps to make it more descriptive also, e.g. "rangeFrom" or "dateFrom", etc.

Comment: Other database systems use either [brackets], 'apostrophes', or "double quotes", but MySQL uses ``backticks``.

Comment: +1 And for the record, never do this again :) Find a synonym instead: "Sender," and "Receiver" might have sufficed.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT (`from`,`to`) FROM `permissions`
```

**Update**.

Whoops, seems like I'm too slow for this site.

Comment: I'm not used to it yet! And why can't I type ']' on a normal reply? 
That just gets on my nerves